# React MUI X Date Picker can't show date time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Strange bug. Format 'DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm' shows 27/10/2021 00:00, but 'HH:mm' shows 21:47 (right time)
Do you know what can be the issue?

```
<DateTimePicker
  name={"publishDate"}
  allowKeyboardControl
  ampm={false}
  clearable
  autoOk
  label={<IntlMessages id="form.publishDate" />}
  format="DD/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
  clearable={false}
  cancelLabel={
    <span>
      <IntlMessages id={"form.chancel"} />
    </span>
  }
  maxDate={Date.now() + 2629800000}
  disablePast
  minDate={Date.now() + 54000}
  onChange={(value) => {
    console.log("setting value to", value);
    setFieldValue("publishDate", value);
  }}
  value={publishDate}
  animateYearScrolling={false}
/>;
```

**UPDATE**
Via yarn, it is working correct, via npm doesn't work

Comment: try `format="DD/MM/yyyy hh:MM"`

Comment: What is your `react-datetime-picker` version?

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç my bad it is "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",

Comment: @demark-pro show 12:10 ( now is 12:00)

Comment: And what is your localization library for `utils` param of your `MuiPickerUtilsProvider`?

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç @date-io/moment

Comment: additional info via yarn works. npm - no

Comment: If it works via yarn, I think it is most probably related to the version of `@date-io/moment`. Did you try deleting `package-lock.json` & `node_modules` and running npm install?